# view console.log output in angular protractor jasmine test

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

How can I view console.log output in an angularjs protractor jasmine test? As of now, the browser closes by itself too quickly.

more info - I am working with the angularjs tutorial, step 8. I am trying to change the e2e test to protractor. The protractor config file I'm using is based on %appdata%\npm\node_modules\protractor\referenceConf.js. In spec js files referenced by the config file, I have instances of console.log. However, during execution of the protractor e2e test, the web site opens in chrome, I see things happen in the browser, then the browser closes before I can examine any console.log output. I think I need to keep chrome open somehow. How?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your question but if you set a console.log() in your specs, you should see it in the terminal

Comment: @glepretre - the OP says he has console.log() output, but the browser closes too quickly for him to view it.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use `browser.manage().logs().get('browser')`

```
browser.manage().logs().get('browser').then(function(browserLogs) {
   // browserLogs is an array of objects with level and message fields
   browserLogs.forEach(function(log){
      if (log.level.value > 900) { // it's an error log
        console.log('Browser console error!');
        console.log(log.message);
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: As this reads the current state of the browser's logs, it's best off in an `afterEach()` or post-test block

Comment: Where do I add that code block? In the spec file or the config? More details would help.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with latest protractor v3 & firefox

Comment: The missing part of this answer for me was that I needed to add a loggingPrefs section to the configuration file per https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md#how-can-i-get-hold-of-the-browsers-console, e.g.
capabilities: {
   loggingPrefs: {
       browser: "ALL"
   }     },

Comment: I put this in cucumber.After with capabilities: { loggingPrefs: { browser: "ALL" } } in protractor.conf.ts and it worked.

Answer (score 11):

A general misconception is `console.log` will log the things in your browser. That is incorrect. When you run your tests, along with the results of tests you should see the `console.log()` values also in the terminal. Browser console is completely different from this.

A general example:

```
it('get name as John', function(){
        element(by.id('name')).getText().then(function(value){
        console.log(value);
    })
});
```

Results in Terminal:

```
John
get name as John - pass
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 6):

This can now be achieved *without writing any special code* and via plugins:

- first party [`protractor-console-plugin`](https://github.com/angular/protractor-console-plugin) (Chrome only)
- third party [`protractor-console`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-console)

Answer (score 5):

In order to keep the browser's window open you should try running Protractor in debug mode:

```
$ <route-to-protractor> debug <route-to-conf-file>
```

Then in your spec file add this line where you want the execution to stop:

```
browser.debugger();
```

In the Protractor debugger console, you can step over the stops by typing `c` or `cont`.

More info here: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/debugging.md

Now, in order to get the console content you can check how to do it in Protractor FAQ:
https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md#how-can-i-get-hold-of-the-browsers-console

Something like:

```
browser.manage().logs().get('browser').then(function(browserLog) {
  console.log('log: ' + require('util').inspect(browserLog));
})
```

Comment: But that doesn't capture the data from console.log because by default chrome is set to WARNING level so how can someone kick off a test with the webdriver or the browser set to the ALL logging level?

Comment: @pulkitsinghal I figured it out.  You need to change your browser capabilities     loggingPrefs: { browser: 'ALL' },

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to change the logging level to see other types of console outputs.

See my proposed update to the protractor faq to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?returnurl=%2fquestions%2f22082395%2fview-console-log-output-in-angular-protractor-jasmine-test%2f24417431%2324417431)

Answer (score 1):

You could always just override console.log in your test :)

```
logMessages = [];

console.log = function(message) {
    logMessages.push(message);
}
```

You could also use $log instead of console.log and use a solution like this to put some hooks into the log messages: https://gist.github.com/lrvick/6938531

Answer (score 1):

A simple option is to use:

`browser.pause();` [protractor/api/browser.pause](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.pause)

for example:

```
it('should .. test stuff', function() {
    browser.pause(); //--->the automation will pause here - follow the instructions in your terminal to continue 
    //--->your broken testing magic here...
});
```

Place that method call as the first item in the spec body where you need to view the browsers console.

After the browser pauses you'll have control of the automation.  You can then interact with the browser as usual, inspecting elements at different states, checking the browsers console, etc.

Continue the tests by entering `c` for continue in your terminal - there will be a prompt with instructions waiting for your entry.

Answer (score 0):

If you

- install [protractor-console](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-console)
- add this to your config

```
    plugins: [
        {
            package: 'protractor-console',
            logLevels: ['severe'],
        },
    ],
```

this will log all browser error logs to your command line where you run protractor