# Show output on browser console using Protractor

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I want to show messages in the browser's console when executing the tests with Protractor using Jasmine because the browser's console it's more useful and readable and when I use it in protractor with not valid values it always show me a long message like

```
Object {
  closure_uid_824017913: 1230,
  flow_:
   Object {
     events_: Object {},
     closure_uid_824017913: 1,
     activeFrame_:
      Object {
        events_: Object {},
        closure_uid_824017913: 1033,
        flow_: [Circular],
        parent_: [Object],
        children_: [Object],
        lastInsertedChild_: [Object],
        pendingTask_: null,
        isLocked_: false,
        isBlocked_: false,
        pendingCallback: false,
        pendingRejection: false,
        cancellationError_: null },
     runningFrame_:
      Object {
        events_: Object {},
        closure_uid_824017913: 1033,
        flow_: [Circular],
        parent_: [Object],
        children_: [Object],
        lastInsertedChild_: [Object],
        pendingTask_: null,
        isLocked_: false,
        isBlocked_: false,
        pendingCallback: false,
        pendingRejection: false,
        cancellationError_: null },
     schedulingFrame_:
      Object {
        events_: Object {},
        closure_uid_824017913: 1033,
        flow_: [Circular],
        parent_: [Object],
        children_: [Object],
        lastInsertedChild_: [Object],
        pendingTask_: null,
        isLocked_: false,
        isBlocked_: false,
        pendingCallback: false,
        pendingRejection: false,
        cancellationError_: null },
     shutdownTask_: null,
     eventLoopTask_: null,
     hold_:
      { _called: false,
        _idleTimeout: 2147483647,
        _idlePrev: [Object],
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idleStart: 12906,
        _onTimeout: [Function: wrapper],
        _repeat: [Function] },
     yieldCount_: 7 },
  stack_: null,
  parent_:
   Object {
     closure_uid_824017913: 1228,
     flow_:
      Object {
        events_: Object {},
        closure_uid_824017913: 1,
        activeFrame_: [Object],
        runningFrame_: [Object],
        schedulingFrame_: [Object],
        shutdownTask_: null,
        eventLoopTask_: null,
        hold_: [Object],
        yieldCount_: 7 },
     stack_: null,
     parent_:
      Object {
        closure_uid_824017913: 1226,
        flow_: [Object],
        stack_: null,
        parent_: [Object],
        callbacks_: [Object],
        state_: 'pending',
        handled_: true,
        pendingNotifications_: false,
        value_: undefined },
     callbacks_: [ [Object] ],
     state_: 'pending',
     handled_: true,
     pendingNotifications_: false,
     value_: undefined },
  callbacks_: null,
  state_: 'pending',
  handled_: false,
  pendingNotifications_: false,
  value_: undefined }
```

which is everything but useful.

Answer (score 0):

This may help
[view console.log output in angular protractor jasmine test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22082395/view-console-log-output-in-angular-protractor-jasmine-test)
https://ngmilk.rocks/2014/10/17/detecting-console-errors-while-testing-angularjs-with-protractor/)

Comment: I was asking to show in the browser's console the output of the `console.log` command inside the tests and that is for reading the browser's console messages, but I appreciate your help.

Comment: Usualy the console.log output is available in the terminal itself. If not change the `log level` in configuration file. For more info check https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities#loggingpreferences-json-object

Comment: I don't understand what should I do with that. Should I put a new variable in the `conf.js`?