# addMockModule in protractor not adding module for $httpBackend

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I'm adding a mockmodule below to my AngularJS protractor test and it does not seem to be getting picked up. The api call goes straight to the real api. Also when I do console.log(browser) I do see:

name: 'httpBackendMock', script: [Function], args: [] }

None of the console.log statements in httpBackendMock are getting triggered.

```
describe('successful login', function(done) {

    var httpBackendMock = function() {
      angular.module('httpBackendMock', ['ngMockE2E', 'sampleapp']).run(function($httpBackend) {
      var authenticated = false;
      var testAccount = {
        email: 'test@example.com'
      };

      $httpBackend.whenPOST('/login').respond(function(method, url, data, headers) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log("executing");
            return [200, {loggedIn: true}, {}];
      });
      $httpBackend.whenGET(/.*/).passThrough();
      })
    };


    beforeEach(function(){
        browser.addMockModule('httpBackendMock', httpBackendMock);
    });

    it('should login', function(done) {
            console.log(httpBackendMock.toString());
            console.log(browser);
            var url = browser.getCurrentUrl();
            element(by.id('user-input')).sendKeys('someuser');
            element(by.id('password-input')).sendKeys('somepassword');
            element(by.css('.btn-default')).click();
            expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toNotBe(url);
            expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('account-page');
            done();
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add all of your mocks before the `browser.get()` call:

```
beforeEach(function(){
    browser.addMockModule('httpBackendMock', httpBackendMock);
    browser.get(desiredUrl);
});
```

Also, note that `console.log()` calls inside the `httpBackendMock` *would log into the browser's console* instead of your terminal/console from where you've executed your tests. [Check your browser logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22082395/view-console-log-output-in-angular-protractor-jasmine-test) and, if you see `data` value and "executing" printed there, you have the mocked backend in play and the problem is in the way you mock the response.